# Taylor-series of a differential equation

Tags: derivatives

Given a differential equation and i was asked to calculate secondorder taylor-series of $a(t)$:

$\frac{da}{dt} = -ra^4$

where $r$ is a constant.

For $f(a)$ in Taylorseries formula, I can simply take integral but i don't understand how to find $f\prime\prime(a)$ because $a$ is function of $t$.

Can someone tell me how can i find second derivative of this recursive function?

Comment: You might want to apply the Taylor series formula but in this case $f$ is $a$ and $x$ is $t$. Can you calculate a''(t)?

Comment: I understand this but I'm given $a \prime (t) = -ra^4$ , Now on the right side i have no t but $a^4$ which i think again a function is.

Comment: By the chain rule, $a'' = (da/dt)' = -r(4a^3)da/dt= -r(4a^3)(-ra^4)$

Comment: I think they just want you to write $a(t) = C_0 + C_1t + C_2 t^2$ and solve for the coefficients to make the DE true to order $t^2$

Comment: @WW1 I was clearly asked to find taylorsries of order two arround $t=0$.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim Yes, and WW1 is giving you instructions for steps you can take to arrive at the taylor series of order two. Write the taylor series with unknown coefficients and sub into the diffeq. Give it a try!